# ControlID could not be found for AsyncPostBackTrigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="CartUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID='<%= rdoSelect.ClientID %>'/>
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="cartTimer" Interval="5000" runat="server" OnTick="cartTimer_Tick">
            </asp:Timer>
            <asp:GridView ID="gridCartSearch" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <asp:HiddenField ID="Serial" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("serialnum") %>' />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="radioBtns"
                                OnCheckedChanged="rdoSelect_CheckedChanged" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I'm getting the following error

> A control with ID '<%=
>   rdoSelect.ClientID %>' could not be
>   found for the trigger in UpdatePanel
>   'CartUpdatePanel'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID='rdoSelect'/>` but it’s not working.

I found a solution here [A control with ID 'ImageButton5' could not be found for](http://forums.asp.net/t/1192816.aspx).

The AsyncPostBack should be registered whenever a row is created.

```
protected void gridCartSearch_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            Control radioControl = e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("rdoSelect");
            if (radioControl != null)
            {
                cartScriptMgr.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(radioControl);
            }
            
        }
```

Update the Update Panel On rdoSelect_CheckedChanged

```
  protected void rdoSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ....
            CartUpdatePanel.Update();

        }
```

using  `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID='rdoSelect'/>`

Thanks All

Answer (score 4):

Change the following line:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID='<%= rdoSelect.ClientID %>'/>
```

to:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID='rdoSelect'/>
```

You cannot use server side tags inside of a server control (like AsyncPostBackTrigger). Instead you should use the ID of the control and the asp.net runtime will dynamical replace it with the proper client side id.

Comment: I tried that, Its not working. However i got the solution, will update that soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have the client id. Just put `rdoSelect` as the ID. You should also put a tag `EventName` to be `CheckedChanged`

Answer (score 1):

The ControlID is the asp.net control id defined in the aspx markup and not the client id, change it as follows:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdoSelect"/>
```

Should work