# Error when trying to retain updatepanel values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm having a problem with a couple of dropdown boxes in my gridview losing their values upon postback.

Everything is within an update panel so I have tried to include  into my code but this just throws an exception. See the below code, I have a child gridview within a larger one:

I am receiving the following exception when I go to load the gridview: A control with ID 'DropDownNote' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdateGV'.

I followed what was in this post: [Control in UpdatePanel loses value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911816/control-in-updatepanel-loses-value)

But now I'm getting the above exception, what am I missing here? Will solving this problem retain the values of the dropdowns after the postback?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:GridView ID="GVAccounts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="Horizontal" 
    style="position: relative; margin-top: 10px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="branch" HeaderText="Branch" 
                SortExpression="branch" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="no" HeaderText="Account" 
                SortExpression="account" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") + " " + Eval("surname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="sub" HeaderText="Sub" SortExpression="sub" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalAmount" HeaderText="Hold" 
                SortExpression="TotalAmount" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="loc" HeaderText="LOC" DataFormatString="{0:C}" SortExpression="loc" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="locstatus" HeaderText="LOC status" 
                SortExpression="locstatus" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="HoldCalc" HeaderText="OD/EX Amt" SortExpression="HoldCalc" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="odtimes" HeaderText="#OD" SortExpression="odtimes" />

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>

                    <td colspan="100%">
                        <div id="gridChild" style="display: inline; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateGV" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                                BorderStyle="Double"  BorderColor="#5D7B9D" Width="80%">
               <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />

                <RowStyle BackColor="#E1E1E1" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                                            oncheckedchanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" />
                       </ItemTemplate>  
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="effective" HeaderText="Effective" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="desc_" HeaderText="Desc" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="code" HeaderText="TC" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="Amount" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="tracer" HeaderText="Cheq #" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="empltype" HeaderText="Empl" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="balance" HeaderText="OD/EXT Amt" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Note">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownNote" runat="server" 
                                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownNote_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                                            AutoPostBack="True">
                                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>MWC</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>CBM</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Return</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>TSF</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>OK NO S/C</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Note1">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNote2" runat="server">
                                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">NSF</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Funds Not Clear</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Post Dated</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Stale Dated</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Stop Payment</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Encoding Incorrect</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Branch">
              <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddBranch" runat="server" DataSourceID="BranchDataSource" 
                                            DataTextField="branch" DataValueField="branch">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="BranchDataSource" runat="server" 
                                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ThirdPartyDataConnectionString %>" 
                                            SelectCommand="SELECT [branch] FROM [branch]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextNo" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddType" runat="server" DataSourceID="typeSource" 
                                            DataTextField="Type" DataValueField="Type">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="typeSource" runat="server" 
                                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ThirdPartyDataConnectionString %>" 
                                            SelectCommand="SELECT [Type] FROM [DMDType]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub">
                                    <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="TextSub" Width="25px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                           </ContentTemplate>
                           <Triggers>
                           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownNote" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                           </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>   
                        </div> 
                    </td>

                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You could register it in codebehind (see the accepted answer below): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894474/controlid-could-not-be-found-for-asyncpostbacktrigger But instead of `e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("DropDownNote")` use `e.Row.FindControl("DropDownNote")`

Comment: That would have to go in the row_databound event I assume?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's sufficient to use `RowDataBound` or if you have to use `RowCreated`(as suggested by the link i've posted above). The differnce is that the latter is executed on every postback whereas the former will be triggered onyl if your databind the grid.

Comment: I'm still getting the error unfortunately, I tried it both places in the RowCreated and the RowDataBound

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go a different route with this, I added MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" to the top line of the aspx, since the complaint from the client was that the page would go back to the top after every postback. I had originally used the UpdatePanel to remedy this but decided this would be a better option.

Now my only problem is getting the page to retain the values of the dropdown boxes after a postback which I will have to figure out how that can be done.